# Class interceptor does not exist magento 2

Tags: magento2, interceptor

[image]

> Class Vendor\Mymodule\Controller\Adminhtml\Allimports\Save\Interceptor does not exist

I have a custom form and when I save data this error message, how to fix it, except usage di: compile. Thank you.

Comment: You need to di compile again

Comment: run compile di compile command which generates interceptor

Comment: I know, di: compile can fix it, but is there any other way?

Comment: not possible to another way..

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help.

Comment: in what deploy-mode are you working? "development" should generate them on the fly.

Comment: Duplicate [Magento 2 : Class interceptor does not exist](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290344/magento-2-class-interceptor-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 3):

Most probably there is an error in your `Vendor\Mymodule\Controller\Adminhtml\Allimports\Save` class.

Check the constructor for typos or non-existing dependencies.

Comment: Had a similar issue and it turned out to be a bunch of missing dependencies. Thank you for being the guiding light in this dark and scary world of magento!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to go for di compile. Please remove the var/generation folder (For < Magento 2.2) or generated folder (For >= Magento 2.2) and do the deployment, give necessary permissions and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a chance that you have created a function name and earlier you were not passing any argument in that function.
After some changes, you passed one argument to the same function. In this case, an error will come.

So just rename that function name and again run all commands i.e. di:compile. setup:upgrade , s:s:d -f, cache:flush.
It will work.

Kudos if this solution work

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because your class really doesn't exist or because you need to clean up your compiled files and generate them again.

Check if the class exist `vendor\Mymodule\Controller\Adminhtml\Allimports\Save`

Then run these commands below to make sure you have all your required composer packages installed and you regenerated the compiled files.

```
   composer install
   bin/magento setup:upgrade
   bin/magento setup:di:compile
   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar error happened to me.

I needed to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` to get a proper error message, which was a stray comma in a constructor of a totally different class.

So if this happens to you, try running setup:di:compile once to see if any stray compile errors occur.