# Magento 2 : Class interceptor does not exist

Tags: magento2, save, interceptor

I have a simple module when I save data 
then this error :

> Magepow\Importexport\Controller\Adminhtml\Allimports\Save\Interceptor
>   does not exist [] []

here is save file

```
<?php

namespace Magepow\Importexport\Controller\Adminhtml\Allimports;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magepow\Importexport\Model\Allimports;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $dataPersistor;

    protected $allimportsFactory;


    protected $allimportsRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        \Magepow\Importexport\Model\allimportsFactory $allimportsFactory = null,
        \Magepow\Importexport\Api\AllimportsRepositoryInterface $allimportsRepository = null
    ) {
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->allimportsFactory = $allimportsFactory
            ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magepow\Importexport\Model\AllimportsFactory::class);
        $this->allimportsRepository = $allimportsRepository
            ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magepow\Importexport\Api\AllimportsRepositoryInterface::class);
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Authorization level
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Magepow_Importexport::save');
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($data) {
            if (empty($data['import_id'])) {
                $data['import_id'] = null;
            }

            $model = $this->allimportsFactory->create();

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('import_id');
            if ($id) {
                try {
                    $model = $this->allimportsRepository->getById($id);
                } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This job no longer exists.'));
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
                }
            }
            $data['config'] = serialize($data);
            $model->setData($data);

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'imports_allimports_prepare_save',
                ['allimports' => $model, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
            );

            try {
                $this->allimportsRepository->save($model);
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the job.'));
                $this->dataPersistor->clear('imports_allimports');
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['import_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e->getPrevious() ?:$e);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the job.'));
            }

            $this->dataPersistor->set('imports_allimports', $data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['import_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('import_id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

I know running the command di:compile will fix, but I don't want to use it. Hope anyone help me. Thank in advance.

Comment: "I know running the command di:compile will fix, but I don't want to use it"
LOL why? There is no other way to solve it, except creating the files which di:compile would create, by hand.

Comment: Duplicate [Class interceptor does not exist magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287370/class-interceptor-does-not-exist-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a chance that you have created a function name and earlier you were not passing any argument to that function. After some changes, you passed one argument to the same function. In this case, an error will come.

So just rename that function name and again run all commands i.e. di:compile. setup:upgrade , s:s:d -f, cache:flush. It will work.

Kudos if this solution work

Answer (score 0):

From my experience:

We should work on `developer` mode when developing. This is because auto-generated classes (Proxy, Factory, Interceptor) will be generated on the fly. DI compile doesn't need in this mode, so we don't need to run it again and again.

And then, we need to delete `var/generation` and clear cache.